# Split and get date and time separately from Google Calendar Api DateTime

Tags: android, datetime, datepicker, google-calendar-api, android-calendar

I am learning android and working on Google Calendar Api
By using this code below in my app

DateTime start = event.getStart().getDateTime();

i am getting this result

2015-12-02T14:15:00.000+05:00

Is there any way to split and get date and time separately in below way

Date : 2015-12-02 
Time : 14:15:00.000
GMT  : 05:00

Comment: You can split at the character "T"

Answer (score 2):

Use [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-ddEHH:mm:ss.SSSX");
try {
    calendar.setTime(sdf.parse("2015-12-02T14:15:00.000+05:00"));
} catch (ParseException e) { }
```

You can use the Calendar object to get any data you want

Answer (score 1):

The code below should do the trick you can change the format in SimpleDateFormat as you wish also the time you get will in 24-hour clock format (hour:minutes:seconds:milliseconds)

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
Date today = cal.getTime();
SimpleDateFormat sdfD = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/YYYY");
date = sdfD.format(today);
SimpleDateFormat sdft = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss:SSS");
time = sdft.format(today);
```